# filter out related products from mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation

Product document:

```
title: 'product title',
price: 240,
tags: [ 'snacks', 'vegetable' ],
```

User search query: `/search?tags=snacks,fruit,juice`. Here, user selected multiple tags (`snacks, fruit and juice`). I want to select all documents that contain at least one of the tags user searched for using mongodb aggregation pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

`$in`

```
db.collection.find({
  "tags": {
    "$in": [
      "snacks",
      "fruit",
      "juice"
    ]
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kOrL3b_SKRL)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$in` operator to find documents where a field contains any item in a given array.

```js
{
  tags: { 
    $in: ['snacks', 'fruit', 'juice' ]
  }
}
```